# How to transmit an Android Object over a Socket?

Tags: android, sockets, object

I would like to transmit an Android Object over a Socket with low overhead.
Should I use standard java.io.Serializable or android.os.Parcel?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your message is longer, more complex or otherwise you need more efficiency, I would recommend to try use [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). They would allow some reasonable amount of alterations like adding new fields, or removing previously optional fields, or adding a completely new structure as a field. However you will also have the real classes with the real setters and getters (can be immutable versions or mutable builders, how do you prefer). Stricter control over that do you put is not as bad thing as may appear.

> think XML, but smaller, faster, and simpler

The major drawback of serialized objects is **not** that you cannot alter the protocol details later. Differently, you can do many compatible changes if you introduce versions numbers and you cannot rename the property name in JSON either if you want legacy client to find that property.

However serialized objects are Java specific and you cannot have a more efficient C++ server client or use Python for prototyping, for instance, if you decide in the future. Protocol buffers are language neutral.

Answer (score 2):

Neither.

Parcel is designed for IPC, and other uses are albeit arguably efficient, dangerous. The documentation says

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

This also means that you need to be sure that the remote side has got the *exact* same version of Android and of your code to be sure it will work.

Serializable has similar problems, and in the (android) dcumentation there is even a hint towards the solution:

> Warning: this interface limits how its implementing classes can change in the future. By implementing Serializable you expose your flexible in-memory implementation details as a rigid binary representation. Simple code changes--like renaming private fields--are not safe when the changed class is serializable.
>
> [...]
>
> Recommended Alternatives: JSON is concise, human-readable and efficient. Android includes both a streaming API and a tree API to read and write JSON. Use a binding library like GSON to read and write Java objects directly.

If you want to move data from one device to another, I think you are better off creating a protocol for the data, ship it over, and populate the remote objects with that data. JSON is probably a good place to start.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean that if receiving side is also running Android, I can use Parcel with ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream to reconstruct the Object?

Comment: Well, no, rather the contrary. For parcel to work in this, you need to have the exact same version of android and the exact same version of your code on both devices. As soon as anything deviates, you will get spurious errors that are not recoverable.

If you create your own protocol, you will be able to parse it so that you can update it and keep backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Transmitting an object through a socket depends a lot on what will be receiving the object. Usually such a transfer relies on a text-based serialisation such as XML or JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If my receiving device is also a Android device, could I use Parcel with ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream to reconstruct the Object in receiving side?

Answer (score 1):

First, define an object to send. As an example, we can define a class called Message to encapsulate our communications:

```
 public class Message implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; // Your version number

    private int    senderID;
    private String messageText;

    public Message(int id, String text) {
        senderID    = id;
        messageText = text;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return messageText;
    }
}
```

Next, instantiate the object, wrap the socket's streams in object streams, then send the message across the socket:

```
Message sayhey = new Message("123456789", "Hello");

Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

out.writeObject(sayhey);
```

On the other side of the socket, the message can be retrieved and used by invoking methods on the returned object:

```
ObjectInputStream in  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
Message messageObject = (Message) in.readObject();
String messageText = messageObject.getText();
```

you can implement Serializable.

Comment: Add serialVersionUID to your class, this will keep it compatible after you do changes like adding or removing new fields or even public methods.